# How to write PHP if statement with an or

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to write a conditional for a variable that is translated. The values are "Other" and "Autre".

This is my code here is

```
<?php if ( $item->name != "Other" ) : ?>
    <span><?php echo $item->name; ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This code works, and if I change "Other" to "Autre" it works on the translated page. If I use this code here the conditional does not work -

```
<?php if ( $item->name != "Other" || "Autre" ) : ?>
    <span><?php echo $item->name; ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How can I write this with an or?

Comment: You need to do it like `$item->name != "Other" || $item->name !="Autre"`. You can't just put the OR between the two strings as you have. You could `echo "Other" || "Autre"` and see what you get - not what you expect in your code.

Comment: Since you test the same lvalue with the same consequences, you can use `in_array`: `if (!in_array($item->name, ['Other', 'Autre'])):`

Comment: @droopsnoot except that that code doesn't make any sense either. *Every* value is at least one of (unequal to "Other") and (unequal to "Autre").

Comment: @hobbs - oh yes, of course it is. I spent too much time trying to correct the syntax but didn't look at whether it made any sense or not.